# Moving a view with animation is crashing my app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I would like to move a view (change its position) with animation. For testing I'm using my physical phone which is Android 9. Moving on one axis is working fine:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "translationX", 100f).apply {
    duration = 2000
    start()
}
```

However, implementing the PathInterpolator crashes my app, the activity just opens for half a second and then the app shuts down, and I'm not getting an error message at all:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    val path = Path().apply {
        arcTo(0f, 0f, 1000f, 1000f, 270f, -180f, true)
    }
    val pathInterpolator = PathInterpolator(path)
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(draggableImage1, "translationX", 200f).apply {
        duration = 5000
        interpolator = pathInterpolator
        start()
    }
}
```

This code isn't even mine, and was copied from Google docs: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view#kotlin

They note that this pathInterpolator is available from Android 5.0 and I'm using version 9 (and there is an if statement to check it anyway). Why isn't it working, and instead crashes the app completely (without even giving me an error log)?